# How to have Bash interpret output from command as quoted strings?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I have a program that gets the files selected in the graphical IU (in my case Finder in macOS). The output is something like

```
'/tmp/file number one.txt' '/tmp/file number two.txt'
```

Note the space char in the names, thus the file names are enclosed in ' (single straight ticks)

When using the output of that command in a command substitution in bash for e.g. the `ls -l` command everything is screwed up. For a test I put the above line into a simple one-liner text file and use it as command line substitution:

```
$ cat /tmp/files.txt
'/tmp/file number one.txt' '/tmp/file number two.txt'
$ ls -l $(</tmp/files.txt)
ls: "'/tmp/file: No such file or directory
ls: '/tmp/file: No such file or directory
ls: number: No such file or directory
ls: number: No such file or directory
ls: one.txt': No such file or directory
ls: two.txt'": No such file or directory
```

The same happens when I assign the file name string to a variable and use it

```
$ xxx="'/tmp/file number one.txt' '/tmp/file number two.txt'"
$ ls -l $xxx
ls: '/tmp/file: No such file or directory
ls: '/tmp/file: No such file or directory
ls: number: No such file or directory
ls: number: No such file or directory
ls: one.txt': No such file or directory
ls: two.txt': No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to solve this? Copying the escaped file names right onto the command line works as expected

```
$ ls -l '/tmp/file number one.txt' '/tmp/file number two.txt'
-rw-r--r--  1 tester  wheel     0B Jul 17 17:21:11 2021 /tmp/file number one.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 tester  wheel     0B Jul 17 17:21:16 2021 /tmp/file number two.txt
```

My ultimate goal is to use the current Finder selection (which I get through a compiled  Applescript) to be available for use in bash. `ls` is just an example, I might want to use the list of files for `tar`, `cp`, `mv` or any other file handling stuff.

Comment: Your string is undergoing word splitting, according to your `$IFS`.  Are the results really seperated by a space, not by a tab character?

Comment: you're not looking to stop splitting, it seems to me, but looking to interpreting the output using the shell's quoting rules, right? Because that's different, you have a space there in the middle of the string you _want_ to split on, the one between the first ending and second starting quote.

Comment: What does the file look like if you select a `Don't let me down.mp3` file for instance or one containing newline characters?

Comment: Is that Finder doing that? or some other program?  Can you fix/configure whatever it is so that it doesn't output the filenames in such a useless format?   NUL separated filenames would be ideal, as that allows for ANY valid filename.

Comment: @cas has a point. While the format *looks* good it is surprisingly hard to handle. Even a simple newline would help, what `ls` does when its output does not go to a terminal.

Comment: Billions of dollars could have been used to feed starving children if wisdom had prevailed and whitespace had been banned from path names.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, ...that's not wisdom any more than making SQL databases unable to put `'`s inside strings in wisdom. There's nothing wrong with spaces; there's plenty wrong with _using spaces as delimiters_. If characters that can't exist in C strings (of which we have a perfectly good candidate, the NUL) are used to delimit lists of C strings, nobody has any problem. Thus, right-thinking people should use `printf '%s\0' *.txt` to generate machine-readable lists of files whose names end in `.txt`, and `xargs -0` to act on such lists. This is a `sh` spec problem, not a filename problem.

Comment: (`xargs -0` of course is not strictly needed; `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do operate_on "$filename"; done` is perfectly functional, if one has a shell with the requisite extensions; extensions being needed is why I assert that the POSIX `sh` spec is inadequate-to-task).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, there is something to be said for the ability to process plain text files that are hand crafted or obtained from elsewhere. It seems natural. The reason that all shells perform whitespace word splitting is surely that spaces in paths were only a theoretical possibility when Unix was developed, much like tabs or newlines are today. There is a reason that `/var/` is not named `/var files/`.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, I disagree with tabs and newlines in filenames being "only theoretical". They happen in the wild, even if rarely, and good software design would account for that possibility _and all other possibilities_. Thinking rigorously about boundary conditions (designing for them, testing their handling) is one of the things our profession is supposed to be good at. Training people that it's _their_ responsibility to think about and handle boundary cases, instead of the OS's responsibility to put up guardrails for them, is a concrete step towards making this better.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I totally agree with your general reflections. I'm only adding that by defining sensible boundary conditions we can make it much easier, cheaper and less error prone to rigorously observe them. In the [words of David Wheeler](https://dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html): "Adding some tiny limitations on legal Unix/Linux/POSIX filenames would be an improvement" and "Spaces in filenames can cause problems; it’s probably hopeless to ban them outright"... but he seemed to want to do that if he could.

Answer (score 6):

Assume you have this string, literally, with the single quotes embedded:

```
'/tmp/file number one.txt' '/tmp/file number two.txt'
```

You noticed it works correctly when given inline as part of a command line, but not when it comes from an expansion. It doesn't really matter if it's variable expansion or a command substitution, the rules are the same for both. Unquoted expansions undergo word splitting, which you don't want here, since splitting on spaces would split between `/tmp/file` and `number`. Quoted expansions don't undergo splitting, but you don't want that either, since presumably you want splitting between the two middle single quotes. Also, there's the fact that *quotes resulting from expansions don't quote anything*. So, we need to do something different.

Assuming the output is known to be shell syntax, and is safe, you can use `eval` to have the shell do another round of processing to interpret the quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="'/tmp/file number one.txt' '/tmp/file number two.txt'"
eval "ls -ld -- $input"
```

or put them in an array for future use:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="'/tmp/file number one.txt' '/tmp/file number two.txt'"
eval "files=($input)"
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    printf "<%s>\n" "$f"
done
```

Note that if the string going to `eval` contains unquoted or double-quoted command substitutions (e.g. `/dir/$(uname -a)`, but not `'/dir/$(uname -a)'`), then your shell *will* execute the commands involved while processing the `eval`. Similarly if the string contains an unquoted `)` to end the array assignment. So, better make sure to only use this with sources that are under your control.

Also, you do need the double quotes around the string being `eval`'d, because you don't want it split and globbed before `eval` gets to process the quotes.

---

There might be ways using other tools to interpret the quotes but not process expansions, e.g. `xargs` takes quoted strings by default. E.g. this would run `printf`¹ with each filename as an individual argument:

```
printf '%s\n' "$input" | xargs printf ":%s:\n"
```

Or run `ls` on them:

```
printf '%s\n' "$input" | xargs ls -ld --
```

Or you could have `xargs` run something that then prints the filenames in a simpler format which you can then load to an array in the shell. (This is a bit backward, but I don't know of a way to have Bash just do quote processing without processing expansions.)

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -td '' files < <(
  printf '%s\n' "$input" | xargs printf "%s\0")
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    printf "<%s>\n" "$f"
done
```

(Here, the `printf` outputs the strings terminated with NUL bytes, and `readarray -td ''`² expects output in that format. The NUL being the only value that can't appear in a filename, that's an unambiguous and relatively simple format.)

But note that `xargs` has a different idea of the exact quoting rules than the shell. It doesn't know about the `$'...'` style of quoting³, which Bash uses in some cases to output values that contain e.g. embedded newlines, it doesn't recognise backslash inside double quotes<sup>4</sup>... But if the output from Finder is just single quotes (and backslashes to quote any hard single quotes), you might be fine.

---

<sup>¹ the standalone `printf` utility, not the `printf` builtin of your shell, at least once even on empty input (except on some BSDs) and possibly more than once if the list is large</sup>

<sup>² requires bash 4.4 or above</sup>

<sup>³ introduced by ksh93 in the 90s</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup>`xargs` came with PWB Unix in the late 70s and the quoting syntax is similar to that of the pre-Bourne `sh` there (Mashey shell), not that of the Bourne shell, let alone ksh93 or bash</sup>

Comment: I suppose for commands that work like `ls` and take file names as end-arguments one can simply feed it with `xargs`, in the OP's example `cat /tmp/files.txt | xargs ls -d`. No need to edit the strings first.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, oh yes indeed, that too.

Answer (score 6):

If switching to `zsh` is an option¹, you could use its `z` and `Q` parameter expansion flags that are designed for that:

```
file_content=$(</tmp/files.txt)
quoted_strings=(${(z)file_content})
strings_with_one_layer_of_quotes_removed=("${(Q@)quoted_strings}")
ls -ld -- "$strings_with_one_layer_of_quotes_removed[@]"
```

Or all in one go:

```
ls -ld -- "${(Q@)${(z)$(</tmp/files.txt)}}"
```

That assumes the syntax of the quoting in the file is compatible with that of `zsh`.

See also the `Z` parameter expansion to tweak how the parsing is done. For instance, if the file contains comments (with `#`) which should be ignored and has more than one line, you'd want:

```
ls -ld -- "${(Q@)${(Z[Cn])$(</tmp/files.txt)}}"
```

See `info zsh flags` for details.

---

<sup>¹ I hear `zsh` is now the default interactive shell in newer versions of macos</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to **fix whatever's generating such useless file lists so that it generates NUL-separated output instead** (because a NUL is the **only** character that can not be in a path/filename, it is the only separator that is guaranteed to handle any filename with any valid characters).  If that's impossible, you can kludge up a "fix" by attempting to convert it to NUL-separated format.

The following perl one-liner will (mostly) convert the file to NUL separated filenames, without quotes surrounding them:

```
perl -0 -pe "s/'\s+'/\0/sg; s/^'|'\$//sg; s/\x0d?\x0a\$//" file.txt
```

The first regex replaces the sequence `single-quote, one-or-more whitespace chars, single-quote` with NUL characters (the commas and spaces in that are not part of the pattern, they're just grammatical English list separators).  The second regex removes the quotes at the beginning and end of the input, and the third removes LF or CRLF at the end of a "line".

This is **very far from perfect** - some input is un-fixable because there's no way to know with 100% certainty whether a single-quote or a LF is supposed to be embedded in the filename or not (this is why starting with NUL-separated files is the correct solution, not trying to kludge it after the fact).

For example, it will fail if any filenames have an embedded single-quote at either the beginning or end of the filename, or if they have an embedded single-quote followed by one-or-more whitespace characters and followed by another single-quote (e.g. `' '`) - all of these will also be replaced with a NUL because of the `/g` global modifier to the first regex (which is necessary for it to match all filenames in the input instead of just the first).  And probably a few other corner-case I haven't thought of yet.

You can redirect the output to another file, feed it into `xargs -0r`, or use it with the bash built-in `readarray` and process substitution to populate an array:

```
readarray -d '' files < <(perl -0 -pe "s/'\s+'/\0/sg;
                                       s/^'|'\$//sg;
                                       s/\x0d?\x0a\$//" file.txt)
```

If you pipe the output into `xxd` (or `hd` or `hexdump` or similar hex-dumper program), you can see that it has become NUL-separated:

```
00000000: 2f74 6d70 2f66 696c 6520 6e75 6d62 6572  /tmp/file number
00000010: 206f 6e65 2e74 7874 002f 746d 702f 6669   one.txt./tmp/fi
00000020: 6c65 206e 756d 6265 7220 7477 6f2e 7478  le number two.tx
00000030: 74                                       t
```